nodejs child process spawned, determine origin of childProcess.stdout.on "data"
if you spawn a persistent child process in nodejs, a bash shell:
childProcess = cp.spawn('bash', { shell: true, serialization: "json" });

and then send (childProcess.stdin.write) it commands (multiple times) that take a different amount of time to execute:
command_100ms = "some bash code that takes ca. 100ms to execute"
command_01sec = "some bash code that takes ca. 1 sec to execute"
command_02sec = "some bash code that takes ca. 2 sec to execute"
and so on..

when each one is done executing and the stdout.on "data" event fires (multiple times):
childProcess.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
    console.log(`Data from child process: ${data}`);
});

how do you determine to which command does a response correspond?
